# How to print keywords into margin?

Tags: marginpar

Many documentations and textbooks print essential keywords of a paragraph into the margin. Is there any package for this?

Of course it wouldn't be all too complicated to define a custom command based on `\marginpar`, but you'd think there's already something out there with nice features like automatic index integration.

Answer (score 2):

The [marginnote](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/marginnote) package provides a command that allows to set text in the left or right margin.

```
\marginnote[Text in left margin]{Text in right margin}
```

Also some document classes provide special commands to set small notes in the margins.

Comment: Does it allow for automatic indexation?