# How to get "paragraph keywords"?

Tags: packages, paragraphs

Sometimes, especially in large textbooks, you find descriptive keywords like "Model Definition" to the left/right of the normal text flow. They help to quickly orient yourself in a lengthy text with many paragraphs. It usually looks like this:

```
                   and therefore we now define the model.

Model Definition   A good model covers all the aspects of
                   the real problem, but ignores the de-
                   tails. [...]
```

What are these "keywords" called? An what package allows me to define them for my own text?

Comment: They are called "margin paragraphs", and you can create some without the help of any package, with the command `\marginpar{<text>}`. Of course some packages will give you further options and more semantic commands (for example for keywords, headers, remarks...).

Comment: @T.Verron: Thank you, that was what I was looking for. Would you mind creating an answer so that it is more visible and I can accept it?

Comment: Another answer is given in this question : [How to print keywords into margin?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65708/how-to-print-keywords-into-margin)
For the future visibility, better mark this one as duplicate than posting separate answers.

Comment: @T.Verron: There's no harm in having answers on duplicate questions, especially if those answers reference the information provided in the other question.

Comment: @CharlesStewart : You raise a valid point, of course. In my opinion, in situations like here, where the questions are exactly the same, and the new answer wouldn't give more information than the other one (actually, the duplicate question even gives *more* information), it felt like an unnecessary spread of visibility. Also, since blubb already found what he needed here, there was no need for an immediate answer. And yes it was partially motivated by laziness. `:)`