# How to write a comment/description?

Tags: comments

[image: How to write a comment/description?]

I want to write comment in a document that is written in latex. Please give me any solution to write like this sample document. please

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) One approach that does not look that comic-like would be to use `todonotes`. Have you taken a look at that package? Can you provide an [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) of your own approaches to that?

Comment: Here are some references: [How to print keywords into margin?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65708/5764); [How can I put real notes in the margin?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78979/5764); [Margin notes with a pointing arrow that are automatically vertically adjusted](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78193/5764)

Comment: Depending on your ultimate goal, this may apply: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140529/graphics-equations-put-text-on-equations/140547#140547.  And here is a different approach: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140310/multiple-lists-of-to-do-notes/168160#168160

Comment: For whom are the comments intended? A fellow writer with access to the source .tex file or the reader of the final .pdf file?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.